# Restricting functions to an isotropy group

Tags: c-star-algebras, groupoids

Let $\mathcal G$ be a locally compact, étale groupoid and let $x$ be a point in the unit space of $\mathcal G$.  Writing $\mathcal G(x)$ for the isotropy group at $x$, consider the map
  $$
  f∈C_c(\mathcal G) \mapsto f|_{\mathcal G(x)} ∈ C_c(\mathcal G(x)),
  $$
  obtained by restricting functions in $C_c(\mathcal G)$ to $C_c(\mathcal G(x))$.

> **Question:** Equipping $C_c(\mathcal G)$ with the norm from the full groupoid C*-algebra of $\mathcal G$, and equipping $C_c(\mathcal G(x))$ with the norm from the full group C*-algebra of $\mathcal G(x)$, is the above map continuous?

**Remark 1.**  I think I have a very roundabout proof of this but I feel there must be a slicker way of proving it.

**Remark 2.**  You may assume that $\mathcal G$ is Hausdorff, but my ultimate goal is to apply this for a non-Hausdorff groupoid (possessing a locally compact Hausdorff unit space).  In the non-Hausdorff case, of course $C_c(\mathcal G)$ should be interpreted as the linear span of continuous functions compactly supported on open, Hausdorff subsets of $\mathcal G$.

**Remark 3.** Replacing “full” by “reduced”, the question has an easy affirmative answer, hence implying the result in case $\mathcal G$ is amenable.